# how to use data in every activity in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-databinding

I am new to android studio.
i am trying to make a app which is a simple guessing game.
in this app every player will enter his name and two numbers.
after every player submits their entries all players will try guessing what other players have entered.
my problem is that i dont know how to manage data in this app.
like storing all entries in list and using them later as condition.

i tried using data class and data object but dont know how to really use it?

Comment: [CodeLab](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp),  [Kotlin Data Class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html), [Kotllin Objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#inheriting-anonymous-objects-from-supertypes), [Kotlin Collections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html), [How to make an app in Android Studio](https://www.instructables.com/How-To-Create-An-Android-App-With-Android-Studio/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As beginner, you can just create public singleton (object in kotlin), and  read/write data to this singleton from each activity on your project

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations-overview